# the way to tune the threshold for the predict method in sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am using gradient boosting classifier implemented in scikit-learn (sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier) for a binary classification problem. Though predict method is provided by default, no clues in the official documents have been shown:

1. how the default threshold is defined,
2. whether there is a customized way for modifying this threshold during tuning models

Any clue and advice will be welcomed

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for 1, I think it's .5

As for 2, when I used sklearn libraries I used predict_proba, which then you can threshold yourself
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.predict_proba
(this way you can also check what is the default threshold by comparing)